# Convert user input into a label using angular.js

Tags: angularjs

What I'am trying to do is convert every user input into a label using angular. I believe that I'am doing the right thing, but is not working. I will appreciate if somebody take a look at this code. Thank you

here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MNdVk6)

```
 <div class="row" ng-controller="tagForm">
  <div ng-click="addEntry()">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 ">
      <input type="text" placeholder="What are your area of expertise" ng-model="newEntry.name" class="form-control border" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 center form-button">
      <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-orange btn-add" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-offset-2" id="up">
      <br />
      <span class="label label-primary" ng-repeat="entry in entries">{{entry.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

app.controller('tagForm', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    return $scope.addEntry = function() {
    $scope.entries.push($scope.newEntry);
    return $scope.newEntry = {};
};
}]);
```

Comment: could you please explain better your issue. you want to convert every <input> to a label?

Comment: What I'am trying to do is that when a user type a word in the input box and clicks add it converts that word into a label. Something like this http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few things wrong in your Plunk, but here's some stuff to start with:

1. You need to wire up a click event on your Add button.  Right now, its not doing anything when you click it
2. Bind to an ng-model on the scope just using 'newEntry'.  All you're typing is a name so thats all you need to save on the scope.
3. Loop over entries, printing out just 'entry' instead of 'entry.name'

And your controller should look like this (no need for the returns)

```
app.controller('tagForm', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.entries = [];
    $scope.addEntry = function() {
        $scope.entries.push($scope.newEntry);
    };
}]);
```

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/smaye81/anrv2qms/1/

Comment: sorry about that. I try what you suggest but still does not work. http://plnkr.co/edit/MNdVk6